# How to add elements in struct in C

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I have the following code:

```
struct home {
    int id; 
    int p;  
    int prio; 
    int rasp; 
};

struct home *P[5];

int new[6][5] =
{

    { 1,  3, 5, 3, 1 }, 
    { 3,  5, 6, 5, 1 },
    { 7,  2, 3, 5, 0 },
    { 12, 1, 5, 3, 0 },
    { 20, 6, 3, 6, 1 },
    { 20, 7, 4, 7, 1 },
};
```

---

I need to add all elements (without the first element from each row) from the array new to the struct home (in a loop). For example, if we take the first row it looks like this:

```
id=3
p=5
prio=3
rasp=1
```

Comment: Why you declared P as an array of five pointers to `struct home` elements?

Comment: Using `new` as a variable name is not a good idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this in the code because your struct does not have padding. So it is more efficient than doing copy element wise. You can just cast parts of the new matrix and assign to struct home pointers in your array of struct home pointers.

```
#include "stdio.h"

struct home {
    int id; 
    int p;  
    int prio; 
    int rasp; 
};

struct home *P[6];

int new[6][5] =
{

    { 1,  3, 5, 3, 1 }, 
    { 3,  5, 6, 5, 1 },
    { 7,  2, 3, 5, 0 },
    { 12, 1, 5, 3, 0 },
    { 20, 6, 3, 6, 1 },
    { 20, 7, 4, 7, 1 },
};



int main()
{
   int i;
   int offset = 1; // exclude first element.
   for (i =0; i <6; ++i ) { 
      P[i]  = (struct home*)&new[i][offset];
   }
   for (i= 0; i < 6; ++i) {
     printf("%dth struct is\n",i);
     printf("[%d].id:%d\n",i,P[i]->id);
     printf("[%d].p:%d\n",i,P[i]->p);
     printf("[%d].prio:%d\n",i,P[i]->prio);
     printf("[%d].rasp:%d\n",i,P[i]->rasp);
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't see how this is different from the answer I posted , except for putting what i wrote into a loop.

Comment: I was writing it at the same time you wrote it.  I posted and saw that you had a one liner with the same code. Either way I  think our solution is better because we don't do any memcopy and we just map the struct layout on to the existing memory in this case.

Comment: Yes, it is a good and quick solution , even with padding because if I'm not mistaking padding would've happened at the end of the structure (or else we could've asked the compiler not to add pading - under GCC it's "\_\_attribute_\_((_\_packed_\_))" ).The only problem might be the fact that the OP might want to change the matrix after adding it's elements to the struct ,without changing the elements in the struct.

Comment: There are a lot of good answers that I was looking for. Thank you all for helping me out!

Comment: Agree. If padding is at end of structure we do not have issue. If there is padding in the middle however due to mixing of integral types like unit8_t and unit64_t then we could easily end up with padding in the middle. But then in that case the person would be hopefully knowing what he/she is doing :).

Comment: Alexie Dariciuc I upvoted your answer, because you were the first person to post officially the one liner and I don't want you to feel I denied you the score, that was not my intention, it just takes longer to write and test complete programs :) .

Comment: @BharathGovindarajan thank you, I upvoted your answer as well because you mentioned padding, I too have tested the program before posting the answer but felt no need to post the printing part and all.

Answer (score 4):

You can do :

```
P[0]=&new[0][1];
```

If you know for sure that your matrix has a valid number of elements required by the struct.

What this will do is link the elements of the struct vector to the matrix so if one element from the matrix changes it changes in the structure as well.

Answer (score 2):

Write a function which does the copy element by element:

```
#define INDEX_ID 1
#define INDEX_P 2
#define INDEX_PRIO 3
#define INDEX_RAPS 4

struct home {
    int id; 
    int p;  
    int prio; 
    int rasp; 
};

int copydata( struct home *h, int row, int arr[][5] )
{
   h->id = arr[row][INDEX_ID];
   h->p = arr[row][INDEX_P];
   h->prio = arr[row][INDEX_PRIO];
   h->rasp = arr[row][INDEX_RAPS];
}
```

Since you know that data are in ascending order, you can use `memcpy` too. But for this you have to use a lot of implicitly knowledge about your data structurs.

```
int copydata( struct home *h, int row, int arr[][5] )
{
   memcpy( h, arr[row] + INDEX_ID, 4*sizeof(int) );
}
```

This is how to call `copydata` in a loop:

```
int data[6][5] =
{
    { 1,  3, 5, 3, 1 }, 
    { 3,  5, 6, 5, 1 },
    { 7,  2, 3, 5, 0 },
    { 12, 1, 5, 3, 0 },
    { 20, 6, 3, 6, 1 },
    { 20, 7, 4, 7, 1 },
};

struct home *P[6];
for ( int row = 0; row < 6; row++ )
{
   P[row] = malloc( sizeof(struct home) );
   copydata( P[row], row, data );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make an array of all the variables, and make enum with their names.

Then you can insert the values from your array.